# AFNetworking 2.0 - Handle error returning status code 200

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am connecting to an API that when returning an error will return the following:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "reason": "Could not authenticate successfully with given credentials",
  "errorCode": "invalidCredentials"
}
```

It has a `Content-Type` of `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and a `Status Code` of `200`.

At the moment, when I make the network call, my success block has to figure out if it got an actual successful response or an error as above. Is it possible however to get it to call the failure block if it gets a response such as above (where success = false)?

*Note:* All error responses will be in the same format as above with a `success`, `reason` and `errorCode` field.

I can supply some of my `AFNetworking` code if required but really i'm just looking for some pointers (and maybe small code examples) of how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` and implement `validateResponse:data:error:` to check the response.

Be careful when using custom `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`. Problems arise when using web-API that are inconsistent (which I find many to be). You need to account for these inconsistency *somewhere* in your code. `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` introduces another layer of abstraction into your code which can complicate things when deciding how to address the inconsistencies.

Comment: This looks like a good suggestion. Do you maybe have some example code or a link to some tutorial/explanation as i'm not fully understanding what I should do inside the `validateResponse:data:error:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager class and override its GET/POST methods, so that the success block already handles the predefined format inside.

Comment: If taking this approach, should I not subclass `AFHTTPSessionManager` as suggested in the [AFNetworking documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.4.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html) for `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`?

Comment: If u need sessions, yes. If you currently do not work with SessionManager, I would not introduce it just because of your requirement